# Build error when using iOS6 If Statement in xCode 5 Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

I am building a project in XCode 5 with Deployment Target 6.1 and SDK 7.0 but I am getting an error on this line:

```
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
```

The error says ***Use of undeclared identifier 'NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1***

Comment: Do you need to include NSObjCRuntime.h

Comment: Where would I add this?

Comment: At the top of the file that is reference the NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1

Comment: What lien of code wuld I write, Im new to this so would appreciate some help

Comment: Why do you think you need this line of code? Chances are there is a better approach.

Comment: How else should I do it lol? I need a solutiion pls

Comment: Why are using this `if` statement? Show a bit more of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work in iOS7. Please cross check your Base SDK version once again.

```
Project Target -->Build Settings -->Base SDk
```

Its a part of `Foundation.framework` `NSObjCRuntime.h` class. So make sure you have the `Foundation.framework` under  `Project Target -->Build Phases -->Link Binary With Libraries` section.

If it's not availabe, click on the + button and add the `Foundation.framework` in to your project.

**Note:**

This can happen when you try to run code built for iOS 7 Base SDK on Xcode 4.x, or if you compile against an older Base SDK in Xcode 5.

The solution is to define what isn’t defined manually using a Macro. Add this to every class that’s complaining and you should be fine.

```
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 993.00
#endif
```

This tells the compiler to define the value if it’s not there, so it has no reason to complain.

Comment: The OP states the Base SDK is iOS 7. None of this should be needed.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have modified my answer. A good edit will be appreciated.