# When one iphone is connected to xcode6 two devices are coming

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode-organizer

When one iphone is connected to xcode6 two devices are coming like

6.1.6(xxxx),iphone 3GS,armv7,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

6.1.6(xxxx),iphone 3GS,armv7,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

in target.i changed architecture to armv7 armv7s to support for both ios6 and ios 7

if i select first one some errors are coming in code at some line .But if i select second one no error is coming for the same line . can you explain the reason and how to avoid it to come alway one .

Thanks

Comment: show the error plz..

Comment: error:use of undeclared identifier NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247319/build-error-when-using-ios6-if-statement-in-xcode-5-project

Comment: ok.But i have so many errors.

Comment: my problem is not errors .it is why two and why two different situations